# 「Linuxでマウスとキーボードが反応しなくなる問題」を調査する方法を教えてください

Tags: ubuntu

## 環境

- Xubuntu 18.04 LTS
- 有線キーボード(FILCO Majestouch FKB108M)
- 無線マウス（Logicool M950t)

## 発生している問題

1週間に1回ぐらいの頻度で、仕事用PCに接続しているマウスとキーボードが反応しなくなります。
マウスカーソルは動きますが、クリックできません。

反応しなくなるきっかけは分かっていませんが、Chromeでページを開いたときなどに発生しました。
負荷の高い処理は行っていません。

この状態になったら、PCを再起動しています。

## 質問

この問題を解決するには、どのような調査を行えばよいでしょうか？
「マウスとキーボードが反応しなくなる」ときに、何等かのログが出ていれば、調査できそうなのですが、見るべきログなどはありますか？

## 補足

journalctrlコマンドの出力結果です。マウスが反応しなくなった部分を抽出しました。

```
8月 10 11:45:01 my-computer CRON[5831]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
8月 10 11:46:01 my-computer CRON[5946]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
8月 10 11:46:01 my-computer CRON[5947]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
8月 10 11:46:01 my-computer CRON[5946]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
8月 10 11:46:43 my-computer kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: write fault at 0000240000 engine 00 [GR] client 0f [GPC0/PROP_0] reason 02 [PTE] on channel 2
8月 10 11:46:43 my-computer kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 2: killed
8月 10 11:46:43 my-computer kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
8月 10 11:46:43 my-computer kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
8月 10 11:46:43 my-computer kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: engine 6: scheduled for recovery
8月 10 11:46:43 my-computer kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1491]: channel 2 killed!
8月 10 11:47:01 my-computer CRON[6195]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
8月 10 11:47:01 my-computer CRON[6197]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
8月 10 11:47:01 my-computer CRON[6195]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

「nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1491]: channel 2 killed!」というメッセージが出ていました。

社内の詳しい人に相談したところ、追加のドライバを「X.Org X Server」から「NVIDIA Driver Metapackage...」に変更した方がよいとのことで、以下の様に変更しました。
変更して1か月の間、特に問題がなければ、質問をcloseします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下は何か問題が起きた時に通常見るものだと思います。

- systemd が使われている OS なら `journalctl`
- `/var/log/` 以下のファイルを(ディレクトリもあるならその中も含めて)一通り

これらに加えて、今回はキーやマウスの問題ということで、以下も有効かもしれません。いずれも「別端末から ssh」が必要ですが。

- libinput を使っているなら、症状が発生している状態で別端末から ssh し、`sudo libinput debug-events` を実行してキーやマウスの操作をして、出力を確認する (症状が発生していない時の出力と比較する)
- 症状が発生している状態で別端末から ssh し、`xev` を起動し、xev のウィンドウを focus してマウスやキーの操作をして、出力を確認する (症状が発生していない時の出力と比較する)
- 症状が発生している状態で別端末から ssh し、xscreensaver の画面にできるかどうかを試みる (`Can't grab` などのメッセージによりできなければ、キー入力やマウス入力が何らかのアプリケーショに grab されている可能性がある)